# Downside of resource owner password flow for native mobile apps?

Tags: authentication, authorization, oauth2, mobile-app, oidc

I have seen some similar questions a few years old and I am not sure if there are any new changing views on this.

I see that this flow is not recommended for mobile native apps. What are the practical downsides security wise of using this flow for this case, assuming the app and auth server are managed by the same organization?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the link https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/mobile-device-login-flow-best-practices

It may provide you with the details you require.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/178540)

Comment: Please see the link https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/mobile-device-login-flow-best-practices

Comment: @ThapeloMokole you clearly didn't read my colleague's comment and responded to it with a link. That's the whole point - there can be a link, but you need to add those details in the answer, otherwise your answer is not of good enough quality..